# Is it fine to mutate attributes of React-controlled DOM elements directly?

Tags: dom, reactjs, headroom.js

I'd like to use [headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) with React. Headroom.js docs say:

> At it's most basic headroom.js simply adds and removes CSS classes from an element in response to a scroll event.

Would it be fine to use it directly with elements controlled by React? I know that React [fails badly](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/997) when the DOM structure is mutated, but modifying just attributes should be fine. Is this really so? Could you show me some place in official documentation saying that it's recommended or not?

<sub>Side note: I know about [react-headroom](http://kyleamathews.github.io/react-headroom/), but I'd like to use the original headroom.js instead.</sub>

EDIT: I just tried it, and it seems to work. I still don't know if it will be a good idea on the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If React tries to reconcile any of the attributes you change, things will break. Here's an example:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      classes: ["blue", "bold"]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("modifying state");
      this.setState({
        classes: this.state.classes.concat(["big"])
      });
    }, 2000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="test" className={this.state.classes.join(" ")}>Hello!</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById("app"), () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Adding a class manually");
    const el = document.getElementById("test");
    if (el.classList)
      el.classList.add("grayBg");
    else
      el.className += ' grayBg';
  }, 1000)
});
```

And here's the demo: https://jsbin.com/fadubo/edit?js,output

We start off with a component that has the classes `blue` and `bold` based on its state. After a second, we add the `grayBg` class *without* using React. After another second, the component sets its state so that the component has the classes `blue`, `bold`, and `big`, and the `grayBg` class is lost.

Since the DOM reconciliation strategy is a black box, it's difficult to say, "Okay, my use case will work as long as React doesn't define any classes." For example, React might decide it's better to use `innerHTML` to apply a large list of changes rather than setting attributes individually.

In general, if you need to do manual DOM manipulation of a React component, the best strategy is to wrap the manual operation or plugin in its own component that it can 100% control. See [this post on Wrapping DOM Libs](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md) for one such example.